# How to get Night light option on system menu drop down?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, settings

I keep Night Light ON throughout the day on my Ubuntu 18.04 system due to my eye problems. But sometimes I need to turn off Night Light for a brief time, so I just click on **System Menu** and I get the option to turn off Night Light. Now if I want to turn it ON  again the option is not available under System Menu, I have to open **Settings** navigate to **Devices > Display > Night Light** click  Night Light ON option.

How Night Light option can be made available in **System Menu** regardless of its state?

Comment: I know there is GNOME extension called [Night Light Slider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/) but it can only change display temperature, which means Night Mode will remain ON, which I dont want.

Comment: How *brief*? There is [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1327/pause-night-light/) which disables Night Light for 10 seconds.

Comment: @pomsky For about a minute or two.